# In google drive API, is there a way to recursively looping over all the subfolders?

Tags: google-drive-api

In google drive API, is there a way to recursively looping over all the subfolders (it should include subfolders, subfolders of subfolder, so on).
Also, if I happen to find all the folder ids and find all the files with a specific file name in those folders, what would be a good and proper solution?
-I alreay tried  'in parents or', but it is not working.
-I know I have to use name = in the q.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your current script?

Comment: In what language are you writing your script? As @DalmTo refers, you should only find all elements that match `q = parents in 'FolderID'` where `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`. Also, if you want to find all the files that match certain name use `q:name = 'nameFile'`. You can check [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) for more information.

Comment: I was using PHP, but it should be just related to API. If I do parents in FolderId, then it would loop over the direct children, right? It would be go into subfolder/subfolder of subfolder.

Comment: The logic is, if you want to make it recursive, every time one of the children is detected as a folder, repeat the process again until none of the files contained is not a `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with recursive search?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you really don't need to do this recursively.  You can but it will mean more requests.

If you do a standard file.list using the nextpage token you will make a request for every 10000 files in your drive account.  Store all the responses into a single variable in your application. Then locally you can sort things on parent to find the folders and sort them out.

This will mean one inital request then a request for every 10000 files on your drive account.  So if you have 15000 files in drive then you are looking at three requests to the api.

If you really want to do it recursively you would have a request to the api for every directory you have in your system plus any next page tokens if you have a directory with more then 10000 files.

So if you have 25 folders with files in it. your looking at a minimum of 25 requests to the api.

I did this in [C#](https://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/) a while ago it works but it will eat your quota.

```
 public static Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList ListAll(DriveService service, FilesListOptionalParms optional = null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initial validation.
                if (service == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("service");

                // Building the initial request.
                var request = service.Files.List();

                // Applying optional parameters to the request.
                request = (FilesResource.ListRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);

                var pageStreamer = new Google.Apis.Requests.PageStreamer<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File, FilesResource.ListRequest, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList, string>(
                                                   (req, token) => request.PageToken = token,
                                                   response => response.NextPageToken,
                                                   response => response.Files);

                var allFiles = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList();
                allFiles.Files = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File>();

                foreach (var result in pageStreamer.Fetch(request))
                {
                    allFiles.Files.Add(result);
                }

                return allFiles;
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Request Files.List failed.", Ex);
            }
        }
```

## tip

If file mime type is `application/vnd.google-apps.file` its a folder. Take the id from that and use.

```
 q = parents in 'Id here'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you mean fetch all files first, then from there look for the applicable data? I am not sure if I am following correctly. Then wouldn't it be still requiring quite a bit of bandwidth? Also, if I do parents in 'Id here' and mimeType = 'something' for 'q' then would it be looking even subfolders of the parent folder which has the 'Id' itself? Would it be just going to search for children (one level down only)? Thanks!

Comment: When i do this i normally fetch all the files with out using Q. Stor all the data in a single variable in my system and then when i am done i can sort it into folders.      If you search using Q after each folder and sub folder then you are going to at the very least have a request for each folder and sub folder.  Which is going to be more requests then just a single request requesting everything on drive and using the nextpage token.